# Derive Asymptotic Behavior of the Stable Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am doing my own research into the [stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) and I was particularly interested in how you would determine the asymptotic behavor of the distribution. The distribution is defined as

\begin{equation}
    p(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \varphi(t) e^{-i x t}dt 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \varphi(t; \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \mu) = e^{it\mu - |\gamma t|^\alpha (1-i\beta \text{sgn}(t)\Phi)}
\end{equation}

where $\Phi$ is defined as

\begin{cases}
\tan\left(\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}\right), & \alpha \neq 1 \\
-\frac{2}{\pi} \ln |t|, & \alpha = 1
\end{cases}

The asymptotic behavior is:

\begin{equation}
    p(x) \sim \frac{1}{|x|^{1+\alpha}} |\gamma|^\alpha\left(1+\text{sgn}(x)\beta\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi \alpha}{2}\right)\frac{\Gamma(1+\alpha)}{\pi}
\end{equation}

To be quite honest, I am not sure where to begin with this. I did some manipulation but didn't get very far. I can reason why the location parameter and scale parameter should not matter.

I expect there to be some key initial step to do this but I am just not seeing it. Any ideas on how to proceed would be welcome.

Comment: Does $p$ equal $f$?

Comment: typo - fixed. Thank you.

Comment: I would split the integral into two parts at $t=0$ and apply http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.E20 for each of the two integrals separately.

Comment: Gary - Thank you. I will need to review this as I am unfamiliar with this solution.

Comment: @Gary - Perhaps I am missing something still but the Method of Stationary Phase uses $\exp(ixt)$ and not $\exp(-ixt)$ as in the stable distribution. Thoughts?

Comment: You can write $$
p(x) = \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\int_0^{ + \infty } {\varphi ( - t)e^{ixt} dt}  + \frac{1}{{2\pi }}\overline {\int_0^{ + \infty } {\overline {\varphi (t)} e^{ixt} dt} } .
$$ So you apply the method for the second integral and then simply conjugate the result. My main problem is that the series expansion of $\varphi$ at $0$ is not of the form presented in the DLMF. However, the ideas in the proof of the stationary phase method should also work here. Look it up in Copson's Asymptotic Expansions or Olver's Asymptotics and Special Functions for example.

Comment: I am going to try to work the simplified problem first which only has the $\alpha$ parameter for now. I think I am getting stuck at the point where I define $q(t) = e^{t^\alpha}$. I don't think this takes the required form. For Watson's Lemma. Not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: Does anyone know, how do we see that the above expansion will not work for \alpha=2?
(The distribution will be Gaussian)

Comment: I am also confused how to derive asyptotics for \alpha=1, and why we need log term in the expression.

Comment: I have had no success at solving this. Perhaps it will come with more time.